# Mediaelement.js wordpress plugin works on Safari and Chrome but not IE or Firefox

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've installed the mediaelement.js wordpress plugin on wordpress 3.1.4. I use the following on a wordpress page:

```
[video src='/echo-hereweare.mp4' width='640' height='360']
```

The page renders the video correctly on Safari and Chrome, but on Firefox and Internet explorer, after clicking the play icon, the movie window just goes gray with an X in the center. I've tried both version 2.15 and 2.1.7 of the plugin.

Comment: I gave up on this and used jwplayer. Well worth the license cost for the amount of time saved.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not recognize MP4 video.  Nor does IE before version 9.  You need to encode 3 version of your video - MP4, OGG and Flash and create a source list within the video tag.

Read the following for which browsers play which formats:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

and here is a decent guide on how to write the video tag to payback on all browsers (although the flash embedding for IE is a pain.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-html-5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues after updating to the latest version.  I'm playing an audio file.  It seems to be moving, but no audio can be heard.

Site: http://romeo.nextgend.com

Safari/Chrome: no autoplay, but sound is audible
IE/Firefox: autoplay works (the scrubber moves), but no audio can be heard

******* EDIT **************
I've downgraded to version 2.1.5 and it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work at all in IE9 64 but in IE932 it plays but looks as if it has enlarged the entire frame and is only playing a tiny portion.  This is H.264 encoded video.